# jruby OutOfMemoryError very small example

Tags: garbage-collection, out-of-memory, jruby

I have a question concerning jruby garbage collection. An OutOfMemoryError lead me to the following minimal example. I run it with `JAVA_MEM=-Xmx500m ruby -w -J-verbose:gc` to limit the memory to 500 MB and show the gc output.

```
(1..5_000_000).to_a
(1..5_000_000).to_a
```

This works fine. However, running this:

```
(1..5_000_000).to_a
(1..5_000_000).to_a
(1..5_000_000).to_a
```

I get an OutOfMemoryError (see below for full OutOfMemoryError stack trace). This puzzles me since the garbage collector should be able to free the memory used by the first object.

Output of stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.jruby.RubyFixnum.newFixnum(RubyFixnum.java:211)
    at org.jruby.RubyRange.to_a(RubyRange.java:406)
    at org.jruby.RubyRange$INVOKER$i$0$0$to_a.call(RubyRange$INVOKER$i$0$0$to_a.gen)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:306)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:293)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:131)
    at app.performance.invokeOther4:to_a(app/performance.rb)
    at app.performance.RUBY$script(app/performance.rb:3)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1172823033.invokeStatic_LLLLLLL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1009311031.invokeSpecial_LLLLLLLL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NFI/1072591159.invoke_LLLLLLLL_L(LambdaForm$NFI)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/871997608.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invokeWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:1136)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretName(LambdaForm.java:625)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:604)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI/515921628.interpret_L(LambdaForm$LFI)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NFI/1072591159.invoke_LLLLLLLL_L(LambdaForm$NFI)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/871997608.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invokeWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:1136)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretName(LambdaForm.java:625)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:604)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI/1903586078.interpret_L(LambdaForm$LFI)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NFI/939187759.invoke_LLLLLLLLL_L(LambdaForm$NFI)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/871997608.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invokeWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:1136)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretName(LambdaForm.java:625)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:604)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI/1903586078.interpret_L(LambdaForm$LFI)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NFI/939187759.invoke_LLLLLLLLL_L(LambdaForm$NFI)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/871997608.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invokeWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:1136)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretName(LambdaForm.java:625)
```

jruby version:

```
jruby 9.0.1.0 (2.2.2) 2015-09-02 583f336 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 24.79-b02 on 1.7.0_79-b14 +jit [linux-amd64]
```

Comment: The same code works without errors in ruby even with much bigger arrays. I also tested a similar example in Java and there, too, the garbage collector works as expected.

Comment: try out **9.0.4.0** and maybe compare to **1.7.23** (chances are the new IR runtime is to blame). anyways, do not forget to [report it](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/new) - it sure seems like it should work.

Comment: @kares I think you're on the right track. It works fine with jruby 1.7.23, unfortunately not with 9.0.4.0. I'll report the bug